# MySQL right syntax to use near ',fields terminated by ',' optinally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' ign' at line 1

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, csv-import

I have a csv file which I have uploaded here 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JfYc-7840utoa3k5iamEC-sScPlzsVVK/view
I have created a Table Titanic it has following structure.

```
mysql> desc Titanic;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| last     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gender   | char(2)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| age      | decimal(3,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| class    | int(3)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| fare     | decimal(5,0) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| embarked | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| survived | char(3)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (1.89 sec)
```

I have been asked to use LOAD DATA INFILE Statement to populate this table,
and as per my assignment

> A blank entry for age means that the age is unknown
>   Fare can have more than two digits because money was not base-10 at that time

I try to execute the statement as follows

```
mysql> load data infile '/var/lib/mysql-files/Titanic.csv' into table Titanic,fields terminated by ',' optinally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' ignore1 lines;
```

I get error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',fields terminated by ',' optinally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' ign' at line 1
```

I try following

```
mysql> load data infile '/var/lib/mysql-files/Titanic.csv' into table Titanic,fields terminated by ',' optinally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' ignore
 1 lines;
```

error I get is

```
ERROR 1064 (40000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',fields terminated by ',' optinally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' ign' at line 1
```

If you look at the csv file in the link I gave row 7 has entry

```
Moran   Mr. James   M       3   8.4583  Queenstown  no
```

there is no age mentioned in above row.So age has been assumed to be NULL hence while creating table I used NULL in create table for age.
row 24 has following entry

```
McGowan  Miss Anna "Annie"  F   15  3   8.0292  Queenstown  yes
```

decimal value in fare.

row 87 has following entry

```
Backstrom   Mrs. Karl Alfred (Maria Mathilda Gustafsson)    F   33  3   15.85   Southampton yes
```

has a bracket in column whose title is first.
row 150 has following

```
Navratil     Mr. Michel ("Louis M Hoffman") M   36.5    2   26  Southampton no
```

is having " " which I have in some fields not always.
 I am not able to understand how to use LOAD DATA INFILE statement to use this csv which I have.
I am doing it for learning so I do not want to use any GUI tool.
What is the mistake in above LOAD DATA statement which I am trying to execute?
How can I use load data in this kind of csv where some values like double quotes " " and brackets () appear in some fields and some fields do not have any thing in them they are blank or NULL.

I am using mysql on Ubuntu 19.10.
Server version: 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 (Ubuntu)

**update 1**
as per the discussion in comments here I am pasting the csv file I have as text

> last,first,gender,age,class,fare,embarked,survived

Braund,Mr. Owen Harris,M,22,3,7.25,Southampton,no
Cumings,Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs  Thayer),F,38,1,71.2833,Cherbourg,yes
Heikkinen,Miss Laina,F,26,3,7.925,Southampton,yes
Futrelle,Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel),F,35,1,53.1,Southampton,yes Allen,Mr. William Henry,M,35,3,8.05,Southampton,no
Moran,Mr. James,M,,3,8.4583,Queenstown,no
McGowan," Miss Anna ""Annie""",F,15,3,8.0292,Queenstown,yes
Backstrom,Mrs. Karl Alfred (Maria Mathilda Gustafsson),F,33,3,15.85,Southampton,yes
Ford," Miss Robina Maggie ""Ruby""",F,9,3,34.375,Southampton,no
Navratil," Mr. Michel (""Louis M Hoffman"")",M,36.5,2,26,Southampton,no Byles,Rev. Thomas Roussel Davids,M,42,2,13,Southampton,no

the full csv in text form can be seen here https://pastebin.com/1B1mVYhJ
apart from this here is a screenshot of how it looks at my system when I issue a load data query 
[load data infile query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tysl8.png)

**update 2**

I have done this assignment by changing the definition of table created rather than taking all values as different different data types I took all of them as varchar 
the questions which I was tried  to do are here
http://arshahuja.blogspot.com/2018/01/deit-14610-big-data-analytics-laboratory.html
solution is also there the only problem was using this kind of csv file.
However I am not very convinced by creating a table like this and Loading the data as mentioned in above problem scenarios following table definition solved my problem. But what if I need to use these values like age and class ,fares in some mathematical calculations then how will I go for writing a query which has every thing as varchar?

```
mysql> desc Titanic;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| last     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gender   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| age      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| class    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| fare     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| embarked | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| survived | varchar(3)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

8 rows in set (0.06 sec)

Comment: There is no evidence of fields terminated by ','  in the question or the link, tab delimited maybe?

Comment: ok yes you pointed it correct I was doing this major mistake apart from other spelling mistakes and other improper usage of query.  how to go about fields terminated by statement the fields in this csv https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JfYc-7840utoa3k5iamEC-sScPlzsVVK/view I am not able to understand how are they separated. I am not able to understand what is separating these fields.  I checked in vim editor and I can confirm that fields are spearated by a comma ',' the problem is there are null values in some fields in column age and in some fields in column first we have () or double quotes "

Comment: my above comment is not correct  I could not edit as 5 minutes time window expired, I checked in vim editor and I can confirm that fields are spearated by a comma ',' the problem is there are null values in some fields in column age and in some fields in column first we have () or double quotes " so in load data I am not able to understand how to use them.

Comment: The problem with your link is that it doesn't present the csv file in the raw and we can't use it. I could create a csv file mysqlf but that takes time and might not accurately represent your problem. Any chance you could add a few lines from your csv file as text to the question? Load data infile is not very flexible so it may be that you have to edit the file before load data infile.

Comment: ok I have added details you mentioned in the question as text and if you can copy from pastebin here I have added full csv https://pastebin.com/1B1mVYhJ

Comment: 'I am not very convinced by creating a table like this ' - then treat it as a staging table and insert from here to your actual table transforming any columns that need to be transformed.

Answer (score 2):

You have a comma after your table name.

```
load data infile '/var/lib/mysql-files/Titanic.csv' into table Titanic,fields terminated by ...
```

If you look at the syntax documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html and the example of a complete statement, there is no comma after the table name.

> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test
>     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES STARTING BY 'xxx';

In general, when MySQL reports a syntax error, it tells you exactly at which point in the statement it found something it didn't think matched the syntax rules.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',fields terminated by ',' optinally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' ign' at line 1

The error above tells you it got confused at the comma right before "fields terminated by..."

That's where you should double-check your statement against the syntax reference documentation, or other examples of working statements.

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled `optionally`:

```
mysql> load data infile '/var/lib/mysql-files/Titanic.csv' into table Titanic,fields terminated by ',' optinally enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 lines;
```

Comment: ok yes this was a mistake then how to go about fields terminated by statement the fields in this csv https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JfYc-7840utoa3k5iamEC-sScPlzsVVK/view I am not able to understand how are they separated.